# Resizing panel with flow layout does not invoke the scroll bars

Tags: swing, jscrollpane, java, flowlayout

I have a **containing panel** *JPanel* with a Flow Layout, the **containing panel** is in a *JScrollPane*, the **containing panel** holds a bunch of other *JPanels*, inner panels, in it. All the inner panels have the same dimensions. If there are more panels then the **containing panel** can hold in its **width** then they are gridded downwards, and if there are more panels then the **containing panel** can hold in its **height**, then the inner panels are aligned in the same grid with the exception of the last row which is centered with the row before last.

While I resize the dialog the **containing panel** extends and the layout flow layout perform its duty, but the scroll bars do not appear although the size of the panel exceeds the bounds of the *JScrollPane*.

How do I control the appearance of the scroll bars when I resize the **containing panel** dynamically?

as for the images, they should sum it up:

[image]

**After extending the dialog width:**

[image]

Adam

Comment: A self-contained minimal code sample might help people understand your problem more easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "gridded downwards"? Screenshots would also help. And in general, you use either dynamic layout or scrolling, but not both.

Comment: It's funny that I've never used `FlowLayout` since it's too primitive for any non trivial GUI, so I didn't realize that you were describing its default behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the containing panel implement `Scrollable`, and set the preferred scrollable viewport size according to the width.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JPanel container = new ScrollablePanel();
                container.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
                for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
                {
                    JPanel p = new JPanel();
                    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
                    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                    p.add(new JLabel("" + i));
                    container.add(p);
                }

                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(container);
                scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                    
                f.getContentPane().add(scroll);                    
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(250, 300);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ScrollablePanel extends JPanel implements Scrollable
{
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return getPreferredScrollableViewportSize();
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
    {
        if( getParent() == null )
            return getSize();
        Dimension d = getParent().getSize();
        int c = (int)Math.floor((d.width - getInsets().left - getInsets().right) / 50.0);
        if( c == 0 )
            return d;
        int r = 20 / c;
        if( r * c < 20 )
            ++r;
        return new Dimension(c * 50, r * 50);
    }

    public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
    {
        return 50;
    }

    public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction)
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
    {
        return getParent() != null ? getParent().getSize().width > getPreferredSize().width : true;
    }
}
```

All numbers are hardcoded for simplicity, but you should get the idea.

Comment: WOW, took me forever, the getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() was not called no matter what I did, only the getPreferredSize() was called, so I started from scratch, and then it worked, frustrated I compared the two codes, and apparently the NetBeans generates a setPreferredSize(w,h) in some cases, and once this is set the viewport layout skips the method. Good ridden, this was a bugger. Thanks for your help, I think I got everything I need.

Comment: What's why I don't use a GUI builder :)